# Are the definitions of "core constant expression" and "constant expression" circular?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, constant-expression

The definition of a *core constant expression* depends on the concept of a *constant expression* as can be seen in bullet points (2.7.1) and (2.9.1) of N4140.

§5.19/2:

> A conditional-expression `e` is a **core constant expression** unless the
>   evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:

...

> (2.7.1) — a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that
>   refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization,
>   initialized with a **constant expression**

...

> (2.9.1) — it is initialized with a **constant expression** or

And the definition of a *constant expression* depends on the concept of a *core constant expression*, as can be seen in §5.19/4 of N4140:

> A ***constant expression*** is either a glvalue **core constant
>   expression** whose value refers to an object with static storage
>   duration or to a function, or a prvalue **core constant expression**
>   whose value is an object where, for that object and its subobjects:
>   ...

This seems to defy the basic principles of mathematical logic.

Comment: What's exactly the question?

Comment: Expressions can contain other expressions; that isn't a problem.

Comment: It doesn't defy logic because the expressions in your code form a tree, not a graph with cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions are mutually recursive, but not actually circular.